# IE & Firefox rendering incorrectly but not in Chrome, Safari & Chromium browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

All,

There is a double walled circle and a text. Ideally the text should be rendered within the circle but in IE & Firefox , the circle is coming down and the text on the top. The issue can be seen using the below code.

Any help or advice on how to get it fixed in IE & firefox is much appreciated.

```html
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
      <div style="margin-top: 20px; position: relative; display: inline-block; max-width: 116px; max-height: 116px;">
        <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 418 418" tabindex="-1">
            <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                <g transform="translate(-31.000000, -31.000000)" stroke="#9B9B9B" stroke-width="2" fill="#FFFFFF">
                    <g transform="translate(32, 32)">
                            
                        <path d="M208,416 C322.875228,416 416,322.875228 416,208 C416,93.124772 322.875228,0 208,0 C93.124772,0 -9.09494702e-13,93.124772 -9.09494702e-13,208 C-9.09494702e-13,322.875228 93.124772,416 208,416 Z"></path>
                        <path d="M208,398.666667 C313.302292,398.666667 398.666667,313.302292 398.666667,208 C398.666667,102.697708 313.302292,17.3333333 208,17.3333333 C102.697708,17.3333333 17.3333333,102.697708 17.3333333,208 C17.3333333,313.302292 102.697708,398.666667 208,398.666667 Z"></path>
                    </g></g></g>
                </svg>
        <span style="font-size: 24px; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">400</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please have a look at the help section on [how to format your post and code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I have edited the post.

Comment: Just use an SVG <text> element you can position inside the svg, instead of trying to place a span on top of the svg. So the solution is to just avoid the issue in the first place.

Comment: Any specifics on FF version? It runs smooth on mine

Comment: @Alfabravo , mine is Firefox Quantam 62.0.2 (64-bit) . Nothing specific, just open the html file.

Comment: The issue was fixed by simply changing the display from inline-block to flex. But would like to know, why IE & FF doesn't render inline-block properly. IE is known to have some problems with it but FF should have rendered it properly. Any suggestions/comments will be helpful to know the exact issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The styling you have added to the divs pushes the number outside of the SVG.
I would just avoid the problem in the first place by using an SVG `<text>` element that you can position inside the svg.

You might have to fiddle with the x and y values a bit.

ps: There's also a `<circle>` element you could use instead of a `<path>`.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 418 418" tabindex="-1">
  <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <g transform="translate(-31.000000, -31.000000)" stroke="#9B9B9B" stroke-width="2" fill="#FFFFFF">
      <g transform="translate(32, 32)">
       <path d="M208,416 C322.875228,416 416,322.875228 416,208 C416,93.124772 322.875228,0 208,0 C93.124772,0 -9.09494702e-13,93.124772 -9.09494702e-13,208 C-9.09494702e-13,322.875228 93.124772,416 208,416 Z"></path>
        <path d="M208,398.666667 C313.302292,398.666667 398.666667,313.302292 398.666667,208  C398.666667,102.697708 313.302292,17.3333333 208,17.3333333 C102.697708,17.3333333 17.3333333,102.697708 17.3333333,208 C17.3333333,313.302292 102.697708,398.666667 208,398.666667 Z"></path>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
  <text x="47%" y="49%" style="font-size: 32px;">400</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: This definitely puts the text within the circle. But in FF & IE, the circle is coming below while in other browsers, it comes at the top. Is there any reason as to why this is happening only in these 2 browsers.

Comment: Okay, on changing the display from inline-block to flex, it worked. The circle came on top in FF & IE as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are your constraints, but to render these circles in particular I'd play with `border-radius: 50%` and `display: flex`:

```css
.circle {
  border: 2px solid #888;
  border-radius: 50%;            /* make the border a circle */
  display: flex;                 /* align the content vertically and horizontally */
  align-items: center;           /* same */
  justify-content: space-around; /* same */
}
```

```html
<div class="circle" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
  <div class="circle" style="width: 90px; height: 90px;">
    400
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Just changing the display to flex from inline-block does the trick. Dont know why IE & FF doesn't render inline-block properly.